# Whats is alternative of RETURNING statement for SET in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to write the following query in MySQL and want to use `RETURNING *` like I do that in PostgreSQL:

```
UPDATE guests
SET accompanying_guests=12
WHERE name = 'random name';
```

As I see `RETURNING` statement is not allowed in MySQL so what is an alternative to that?

Comment: There isn't a direct alternative - you need to hand roll, consider a trigger which writes to a log table and query the log table.

Comment: @P.Salmon So can't do that in one query?